# What is this apparent discrepancy between MorningStar and MSCI

Tags: index-fund, growth, morningstar-star-rating

I've been trying to work out what roughly what the performance of a global equity index fund has been over the last 10 years.

Looking on Morningstar I noticed that they have a benchmark index for these kinds of funds "MSCI ACWI NR USD". Taking a random fund, the benchmark on Morningstar appears to have an equivalent growth rate over the last 10 years of 11.01% (11.24 - 0.23)

[image: morningstar_annualised_returns]

I then looked at [MSCI's website and the history of their ACWI index net USD](https://www.msci.com/end-of-day-history?chart=regional&priceLevel=41&scope=R&currency=15&indexId=2591&size=36&style=C&priceLevel=41?_cookiemanager_WAR_cookiemanager_6AZTm7sLbwpQZrd=accept&_cookiemanager_WAR_cookiemanager_pageUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.msci.com%2Fend-of-day-history%3Fchart%3Dregional%26priceLevel%3D41%26scope%3DR%26currency%3D15%26indexId%3D2591%26size%3D36%26style%3DC%26priceLevel%3D41&priceLevel=41&scope=R&currency=15&indexId=2591&size=36&style=C&priceLevel=41) and that appears to show that over 10 years $100 would now be $228.92 which is around 8.6% annualised return.

11.01% is not even close to 8.6%, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index is in USD and you're showing returns for an ETF in GBP. THe difference is the change in currency conversion over that time period.

If you look at the returns of a USD ETF [here](https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/xnas/acwi/performance) you'll see that the 10-year return is 8.53% which is more in line with the actual index.

Comment: Why would a conversion to another currency change the percent return of the index?  Is there a conversion fee?

Comment: It doesn't change the return of the _index_ - it changes the return of the ETF that _tracks_ the index.